# C# TableAdapter and DataSet update with multiple table

Tags: c#, dataset, tableadapter, dataadapter

I'm new in C# and I need some help.

[image]

I just want to update row in Session table by code below.

```
        dbDataSet db = new dbDataSet();
        SessionTableAdapter sessionTableAdapter = new SessionTableAdapter();
        sessionTableAdapter.Fill(db.Session);
        var session = db.Session.Where(s => s.idSession.Equals(new Guid("{0F0B0E1A-950E-4BCE-9C68-6D1387EDAC90}"))).SingleOrDefault();
        session.endTime = DateTime.Now;
        sessionTableAdapter.Update(db.Session);
```

I got an error at "sessionTableAdapter.Update(db.Session)"

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'PaidLog' includes related records.
```

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

At first that I just only tick Enforce Referential Integrity.

But I try to tick Cascade Update Related Fields and It's works !

I don't know why it work.

Anyone know the reason about this thing?

By the way, thanks to Maheep.

[image]

Comment: You must be changing the related fields with each others. Normally, we do not change primary key after it is set. The option you selected means: If I change primary key in master table, propagate change to child table

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all. Session table has foreign key relation with PaidLog. You will have to update child rows from this table first.

See this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx) for more details in the **"Updating Two Related Tables in a Dataset with a TableAdapter"** section

Or you might want to use [TableAdapterManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384426.aspx)